# Simple existing implementation of ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is there a simple implementation of `ICollection<T>` in .NET framework? I.e. a collection class with ability to add and remove items, but without indexing. `Collection<T>` definitely does not fit, as it implements `IList` as well and so elements can be accessed by index.

Exposing `Collection<T>` or `List<T>` as `ICollection<T>` will not work in my case too, because I need to inherit my own class from it, and a class inherited from any other class that implements `IList<T>` will have indexing as well.

I know it is not a big deal to implement one myself, but just thought it should already exist, searched for but did not found anything similar.

Comment: `IList` is not ordered.

Comment: Agree with Cory.  `IList<T>` is just an Interface.  Ordering requires an implementation; there's nothing at all about `IList<T>` that suggests that it is ordered.  Items added to a `Collection<T>`  are most likely stored in the same order in which you add them.

Comment: There is not collections in .Net framework that provide truly random ordering of items... Please clarify what exactly you are looking for when you say that List-like once don't work since they are "ordered".

Comment: My mistake, `IList<T>` is not ordered indeed. But it allows to access items by an index, which is unwanted in my case. I don't need random order, just not to allow to access it by index. Will edit question to clarify.

Comment: Then override `Collection<T>` with your own class, and short-circuit whatever methods you don't want to expose.  Or, as David L. points out below, create an instance of `ICollection<T>` using `Collection<T>`, and only those methods in `ICollection<T>` will be available in the instantiated object.

Comment: It shouldn't matter if an implementation of `ICollection<T>` allows access to elements by index. If you want it to be an `ICollection<T>`, then just expose the `List<T>` or `Collection<T>` as an `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: The problem is that I'm going to expose it as my own class. If I inherit this class from `List<T>` or `Collection<T>`, it will have the index anyway. So I need to inherit it from a class that does not have index.

Comment: @Aleksey Shubin You should probably mention that in the question, because that requirement will have a big impact on the answers.

Comment: @ConstantCoder ok, edited the question. Still I wonder if this approach is good in any case - is it safe to just 'hide' the functionality by exposing the class this way? One can cast an exposed `ICollection<T>` value to its actual class and so can use indexes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a list of classes that implement `ICollection<T>` in the `System.Collections` namespace:

```
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>
System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>
System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<TKey, TValue>
System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet<T>
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<T>
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>
System.Collections.ObjectModel.WeakReadOnlyCollection<T>
```

But all of those implementations add extra functionality, and since you want to inherit from an implementation, but only expose `ICollection<T>` methods, using any of them is not really an option.

The only choice you have is to implement your own. It's easy enough to do. You just need to wrap a suitable implementation of `ICollection<T>`. Here's one that uses a `List<T>` by default, but also allows derived classes to use a specific type of `ICollection<T>`:

```
class SimpleCollection<T> : ICollection<T>
{

    ICollection<T> _items;


    public SimpleCollection() {
        // Default to using a List<T>.
        _items = new List<T>();
    }

    protected SimpleCollection(ICollection<T> collection) {
        // Let derived classes specify the exact type of ICollection<T> to wrap.
        _items = collection;
    }

    public void Add(T item) { 
        _items.Add(item); 
    }

    public void Clear() { 
        _items.Clear(); 
    }

    public bool Contains(T item) { 
        return _items.Contains(item); 
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) { 
        _items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex); 
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _items.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return _items.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

This is going beyond what you're after, but if, for example, you wanted unique items to be stored, you could derive from this and provide a `HashSet<T>` as the collection type to wrap:

```
class UniqueCollection<T> : SimpleCollection<T>
{
    public UniqueCollection() : base(new HashSet<T>()) {}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Hashset<T>
```

should work if you would like it to be unordered with unique values.

[See MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As mentioned in the comments, `ICollection<T>` is an even simpler collection that is unordered and will allow duplicate entries. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx)

```
ICollection<string> unordered = new Collection<string>();
```

Finally, I am not aware of a "simple" native .NET implementation of a collection that has .Add() / .Remove() functionality without exposing an index.  So, to answer your question, it looks like for your niche functionality you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: `HashSet` is very specific collection and its Add may not necessary add items... I'd not use it as "simple implementation" example...

Comment: `HashSet<T>` requires every item to be unique, while `ICollection<T>` may contain duplicated items.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a quick differences:

SortedList

Is the best way to use to by get keys rather index and it is based on binary search. Internally, it uses two lists:  IList and IList. It does not use Dictionary. Thus it does not have any Hash values.

SortedDictionary is same as SortedList. However, the difference is internal development. Sorted Dictionary is using B Tree. Thus modifications are fast, and lookups are same as sorted list.

Difference between HashSet and List is HashSet ensures uniqueness. That means if you try to add the value twice, it will ignore that value without giving any error or duplicating the same.

So if you don't want to use index based then you can use SortedList that is inherited from ICollection and then IEnumerable...

Otherwise HashSet is the best option where uniqueness is important.

Comment: Doesn't SortedList.GetByIndex() mean that it is still based on an index and accessible as such, even though the preferable access method is by key?

Comment: @DavidL agreed, and in addition `SortedList` can be accessed by key, which I don't need too. Not to mention sorting, etc. - a lot of additional functionality, definitely not a candidate for simple `ICollection` implementation.

Comment: @DavidL Yes, you are right. I have just given you clear understanding on various options.  If you just want Add remove then definitely you can goahead with extension methods or otherwise, a new sub class inheriting from ICollection...